# download attribute is not working for MP4 files in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

I've uploaded the MP4 video file to AWS s3 bucket and now I want to download it directly when I click on download button. But when I click on download button it gets open on the browser instead of downloading. Please have a look at the below code -

```
<a 
 href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/safecamz-recording-
 dev/5adecf78c7dc5e6c9da1b550/5ae026967d496413cdc011dc/video/sample14.mp4"
 download>
 <span>download</span>
</a>
```

Comment: It working and downloading the file.

Comment: What browser are you trying this in? Not all browsers today support the download attribute https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp `The download attribute is not supported in Edge version 12, IE, Safari 10 (and earlier), or Opera version 12 (and earlier).`

Comment: @ElliotRodriguez It is not working in all the browsers.